# REST API Post Object

Tags: rest, .net-core, soapui

I have an API Endpoint as below:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]Create command)
{
    await DispatchAsync(command);

    return Created($"Server/{command.Id}", null);
}

public class Create
{
    public string Ip { get; set; }
    public string Fqdn { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public string AddBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime AddDate { get; set; }
    public string LastUpdateBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastUpdateDate { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I would like to test is in SOAPUI or RESTClient (Mozilla extension). My problem is that when I set POST as:

```
"Create" :
{
    "Ip": "123",
    "Fqdn": "123",
    "Comments": "123",
    "IsActive": "TRUE",
    "AddBy": "test",
    "AddDate": "2017-01-01",
    "LastUpdateBy": "test",
    "LastUpdateDate": "2017-01-01"
}
```

in debugging mode my Create object passed to endpoint is null. Any idea how POST should look like?

Comment: are you sure the url is correct? did you add content-type application/json headers?

Comment: also if that's the whole request in there - you don't need the "create": part, just the curly brackets and what's inside of them. make sure your body passes the json linter https://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the "Create:" part.
Just post below json:

```
{
    "Ip": "123",
    "Fqdn": "123",
    "Comments": "123",
    "IsActive": "TRUE",
    "AddBy": "test",
    "AddDate": "2017-01-01",
    "LastUpdateBy": "test",
    "LastUpdateDate": "2017-01-01"
}
```

Also, please ensure your are setting "Content-type" as "application/json" in your request header.